# Why was Parker in “Boogie Nights” so certain of the safe's whereabouts and contents?

Tags: plot-explanation, boogie-nights

Near the end of *Boogie Nights* (1997), Todd Parker convinces Dirk and Reed to accompany him on a visit to drug dealer Rahad Jackson's house.

Only after spending a long time there does Parker reveal his real reason for the visit was to rob Jackson; at gunpoint he demands Jackson hand over the contents of a safe Parker thinks is in his (Jackson's) bedroom.

From what Parker says he's fairly certain where the safe is specifically located and the amount of money and narcotics kept inside. How could he know these things for sure?

Answer (score 3):

##### Todd Parker’s knowledge about the safe’s location and its contents is not explained in the movie, but there are a couple theories.

He could have had prior knowledge of the contents in the safe from others at the club. The owner of the safe Rahad was a money spender and a known dealer. People at the club were always bringing up his wealth and widely unpredictable behavior.

Another theory, [proposed by Reddit User DrBookenstein](https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/401sa0/boogie_nights_todd_parker_spoilers/) suggests that Todd might have been in Rahad's master bedroom before, possibly during a romantic encounter. This theory is supported by the fact that Rahad did not recognize Todd when they met at his house, which might have tipped off Todd to turn it into a full-blown robbery instead of a con.